# Will cutting a bolted lettuce plant allow it to regrow?

Tags: bolting, lettuce

I'm a novice gardener and my lettuce has bolted. Do I have to remove the entire plant from the ground or can I just cut it down to the ground so it can regrow?

Answer (score 7):

Lettuce is finicky and prone to bolt due to the heat.

Once it bolts, it's done.  Here's what I'd do:  Save the seeds from it. They can be planted.

When I've grown lettuces - leaf ones, not head lettuces - I'll make cuttings and there will be some regrowth  but once it goes to seed the growing year is over.  And the leaves that are there will likely be quite bitter.

Save the seeds and then take the plant and compost it.

Answer (score 3):

I would pull it out of the ground and replant. Cutting it might spur some regrowth, but I think the leaves will be bitter.